# retrieve cobol s9(2) COMP onto C variable

Tags: c, cobol

I need to retrieve data from a COBOL variable of the type: "*PIC S9(2)   COMP*" onto a C variable of the type "*int*".

It's stored using two bytes of a string, so I receive it as a couple of chars.

I know COBOL stores decimal data onto a "*S9(2) COMP*" in binary format, so It would be a great help letting me know any algorithm or way to convert it safely.

Any kind of help & suggestion will be welcome.

#### Update:

Finally we decided to change the picture of the variable to 9(3) in the COBOL part of the implementation, because of the endianess problem.

Thanks to all of you for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to treat that as a short, or a 16-bit twos complement integer.  You will need to check for endianess though depending upon which platform originated the field.

Answer (score 1):

The format of **s9(2) comp** will depend on the Cobol Compiler. Most Cobol compilers I know will store it a 2 byte big-endian integer (high byte first; Intel processors store low byte first). Exceptions include

MicroFocus (depends on compile parameters) - normally 1 byte integer
RM-Cobol : Has its own "Binary Format".

If it is a 2 byte integer

- On Big-Endian machine (IBM Mainframe, Power etc) it should be a 2-Byte integer
- On Little-Endian (Intel) you need to swap the bytes around.

Answer (score 1):

The S9(2) COMP indicates it is a left-aligned (bit 0 at the left of word) not explicity synchronised signed numeric field, probably in an internal or pseudo-binary format, that can hold 2 digits and possibly a bit in the word (or in a different memory location) is used for indicating if the value is positive or negative. A cobol program can have a specific method for storing a COMP data item which may not be directly compatible with C. It appears that you need to access and test the sign indicator in a relevant way to check it and you may have to access each of the 2 bytes (2 of 8 bits) or characters (2 of 6 bits), check if they are big-endian or little-endian and put them into a signed integer field in C. A lot will depend on the architecture and compilers of the computer involved in creating and reading in the data field and can be more complicated if 2 computer types are involved.

Comment: This is complete nonsense.